# Apache Kafka- Algorithm/Strategy used to pull messages from different partitions of a same topic by a Single Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have been studying Apache Kafka for a while now.

Lets consider the following example.

Consider I have a topic with 3 partitions. I have a single producer and single consumer. I am producing my messages without specifying the key attribute.

So i know on the producer side, when i publish a message, the strategy used by kafka to assign a message to either of those partitions would be Round-Robin.

Now, what i want to know is when I start a single consumer belonging to a certain consumer group listening to that same topic, what strategy will it use to pull the messages from the different partitons(as there are 3)?

Would it follow the a similar round-robin model, where it will send a fetch request to a leader of a partition 1, wait for a response, get the response, return the records to process. Then, send a fetch request to the leader of a partition 2 and so on?

If it follows some other strategy/algorithm, I would love to know what it is?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ordering guarantee outside of a partition so in a way that algorithm used is moot to the end user and subject to change.

Today, there is nothing terribly complex that happens in this instance. [The protocol](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-FetchRequest) shows you that a fetch request includes a partition so you get a fetch per partition. That means the order depends on the consumer. A partition won't be starved because fetch requests will happen for all partitions assigned to the consumer.

Comment: So yeah, a fetch request for first partition, then second partition and then third, and then we come back to first, and then it goes on and on. 
Would it be fair to say its round robin then?

Comment: or if you cant predict the order, if processing of records returned from previous fetch request of partition takes time, the leaders of other partitions might consider the consumer dead, if they do not get a fetch request. I guess reading the code more could help.

Comment: The consumer has a heartbeat thread that heartbeats to the group coordinator broker to prevent the consumer from being considered dead. Metadata is pulled from the brokers periodically to make sure the consumer knows which brokers are active. You might say round robin but you can't rely on it so I wouldn't say that. If you are just curious about code, take a look at the SocketServer and KafkaConsumer but if you are just making a consumer, know that you can't rely on the order.

Comment: Yes , I am not trying to code anything based on the order of partitions read. Thank u for ur response! Cheers!